# Changing Attributes of json object in Android application (Titanium)

Tags: javascript, android, json, parsing, titanium-mobile

Hi I am developing Android application using Titanium.I want to change value of particular attributes of json object.I tried following code :

```
var row_jsonfeed = this.responseText;
var jsonfeed = eval('('+row_jsonfeed+')');
```

my jsonfeed object look like this :

```
{"feeds":
[
   {"username":"abc","user":"abc","feed":{"description":"dss","id":660,"user_id":1}},
   {"username":"bcd","user":"bcd","feed":{"description":"dddd","id":659,"user_id":1}}
]
}
```

I want to change **username** value so I tried like this:

```
jsonfeed.feeds[0].username = "xyz";
alert(jsonfeed.feeds[0].username);
```

But it's not working.It not giving me changed value of username.Any other alternative way to do this. Instead of **eval** I also tried **JSON.parse** but that also not working.So i need proper way to do this.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your call to eval.  You forgot to concatenate your parens:

```
eval('(' + row_jsonfeed + ')');
```

Comment: Thank you Adam for replay.But I tried that also It's not working.Any other way.Or this is the proper way and some thing I am doing wrong.

Comment: @nilkash - your code looks good, and concatenating those parens like I put in my answer should work.  I don't see anything else wrong with your code.